# There is no improvement when changing from sync to async handler

Tags: python, tornado

I just compared sync and async version handler, and there is no improvement on 'response time' etc metrics, so how to debug in this situation?

Handler

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    calendar = Calendar()
    response = yield (calendar.events())
    self.write(response)
    self.finish()
```

Model

```
class Calendar(object):
    @return_future
    def events(self, callback=None):
        result = # MySQLDB operation
        callback(result)
```

Basic Information:

```
CPU: 1 core
Dababase: MySQLDB
```

Comment: You're not going to see improvement unless the DB operation inside events is asynchronous, meaning it uses a tornado-compatible DB library. Just adding the coroutine decorator to the calling method won't make a synchronous call behave asynchronously.

Comment: why ?I'm not blocking tornado io loop.  Another question is that MySQL is a tornado compatible db or not?

Comment: You are blocking the IOLoop - like I said, adding the coroutine decorator doesn't keep the IOLoop from being blocked. It only gets unblocked when a coroutine uses `yield` to run asynchronous I/O. You're making a synchronous call to a db, so it blocks the loop

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't give a more complete answer, but you should be able to Google search for a tornado compatible MySQL library.

Comment: the cursor always returns data.
you have two options.
* mysql library to add the report to your response
* application side when measuring function write (not recommended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@return_future` doesn't make any sense here. It is used to adapt functions that are already asynchronous (and use callbacks) into something that can be yielded from a coroutine. There is very little reason to ever use it in a modern Tornado application; just use `@gen.coroutine` everywhere.

To run a MySQLdb operation without blocking the IOLoop, you must run it on a separate thread. Install the `futures` package and create a ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(4)

class Calendar:
    @gen.coroutine
    def events(self):
        result = yield executor.submit(mysqldb_operation)
        raise gen.Return(result)
```